# Apache Commons Exec Problems Handling Regex Argument?

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

I'm trying to use Apache Commons Exec to run a git command which uses a regex.

When I form my `CommandLine` and print it out it looks like this:

```java
[git, --no-pager, grep, --line-number, --untracked, --extended-regexp, "^\s*public void\s+(testFindByAdAccount).*", --, *Test.java]
```

However when I execute this, git returns no results, resulting in an exit code 1.

When I run this command manually though, it returns plenty of results and succeeds. Changing the `--extended-regexp` argument to just a string like `testFindByAdAccount` does yield results when run via `Exec`, so I think Apache Commons is doing something to the regexp argument making it invalid. Any ideas what is going on?

EDIT: Adding a reproducible example

1. Clone https://github.com/ragurney/min-example
2. Run `gradlew shadowJar` to produce jar file for project
3. Run the app with `java -jar app/build/libs/app-all.jar`
4. Note the output which shows the command printed fails with an exit code 1 (because there are no results returned by the git command)

```bash
$ java -jar app/build/libs/app-all.jar
HELLOOOOOO
WD:::  null
[git, --no-pager, grep, --line-number, --untracked, --extended-regexp, "^\s*public void\s+(testAppHasAGreeting)\(\).*", --, *Test.java]
WD:::  /Users/rgurney/Src/personal/min-example

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at min.example.App.lambda$runCommand$1(App.java:74)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.getOrElseThrow(Try.java:748)
```

5. Running the command manually does produce expected results:

```bash
$ git --no-pager grep --line-number --untracked --extended-regexp "^\s*public void\s+(testAppHasAGreeting)\(\).*" -- "*Test.java"
app/src/test/java/min/example/AppTest.java:11:    public void testAppHasAGreeting() {
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? Perhaps the way you're putting the CommandLine or Executor together are the problem

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment - I tested, and this most definitely works with Apache Commons Exec. I.e., the issue isn't the regex, but something else (perhaps the cwd? Perhaps handling the output?) We need to see a full example and the output that doesn't work for your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Mureinik. I added a rough MRE, which I think captures the problem.

Comment: No luck - I run the `main` in the sample you provided (using IntelliJ) and it just works. We're missing some environmental difference here.

Comment: How exactly did you run it? Using the steps above? I get the "Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)" exception even when running through intelliJ  any idea what env differences could be the cause? this happens using zsh or bash. Would Java version be the issue? I'm using 1.8. Thanks again for taking the time to run my example.

Comment: Yup, just works, and finds the line that matches that regex

Comment: What version of java are you using? I'm trying to think of what env differences could be the cause here... same with Git.

Comment: Found it! I was testing on my Windows laptop. Once I switched over to my Linux desktop I was able to trivially reproduce the error with the instructions you provided. See my answer below for the details and the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a clue as to what's going on here when the sample you provided worked just fine on my Windows laptop but failed on my Linux desktop.

Once I made sure the git version wasn't the culprit (tested several versions between 2.17 and 2.39 on both machines), I figured the difference must be in the way different shells handle quoting. Specifically, the only argument here that has any potential quoting issues is the regex (`"^\s*public void\s+(testFindByAdAccount).*"`), which is added to the command line by `commandLine.addArgument(regex);`.

`addArgument` may look innocuous, but under the hood, it allows the CommandLine to handle the quoting itself (i.e., `addArgument(String argument)` calls `addArgument(String argument, true)`. Since you've handled the quoting yourself, you should not allow the `CommandLine` to handle the quoting, and should explicitly call it with the second argument `false`. i.e.:

```java
public static List<String> grep(String regex, String filePattern, String wd) {
    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse("git");
    commandLine.addArgument("--no-pager");
    commandLine.addArgument("grep");
    commandLine.addArgument("--line-number");
    commandLine.addArgument("--untracked");
    commandLine.addArgument("--extended-regexp");
    commandLine.addArgument(regex, false); 
    // Here -----------------------^
    commandLine.addArgument("--");
    commandLine.addArgument(filePattern);

    System.out.println(commandLine);

    return List.of(runCommand(commandLine, wd).split("\n"));
}
```

This takes the quote-handling logic away and ensures the same code runs smoothly both on Windows and Linux (at least those I've tested).

Comment: My god. I tried so many permutations of the regex including manually adding quotes but never tried no quotes at all and adding `false` for `handleQuoting`. Confirmed working in both my MRE and my actual project. Thanks so much for this! Will award the bounty when the system allows in 17 hours.